# No me aparece la imagen de mi pagina web en html

Tags: html, imagen, aplicación-web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]No me aparece la imagen de mi pagina web en html en cambio me aparece una imagen pequeña que esta como rota. Al hacer ctrl + click en VS Code me dice "se ha producido un error al cargar la imagen ¿abrir archivo con el editor de texto/binario estandar de Visual Studio code?"
al darle a 'abrir archivo con el editor'... me dice que no se puede abrir el archivo. Estoy usando flask

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial scale=1.0'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <title>Samisaw6</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="agrupar">
    <header>
        <h1>Samisaw<h1>
        <h2>aquí encontraras de todo:  juegos programcion</h2>
        <h3>Estoy aprendiendo programacion con python :)</h3>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <a href=''><li>Pagina principal</li> </a>
            <a href='about'><li>Creador</li> </a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <img src="./imagenes/logosamisaw.png" alt="logo">


    <nav><a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbuYtrNUxg4&ts'>Como aprendi? </a></nav>
    <section>
        <article>
            <h2>primer Articulo</h1>
            <b>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, unde sequi, rem totam ad in officiis corporis culpa facere ut delectus sit optio quidem amet omnis placeat. Harum asperiores placeat blanditiis nesciunt mollitia sit deleniti rem alias officiis! Reprehenderit, natus aliquid molestias eaque alias libero similique. Eos praesentium nesciunt perspiciatis officiis, accusantium vitae dolorem. Obcaecati, ex voluptates cupiditate quae commodi consectetur dolor accusantium nam modi neque dignissimos omnis incidunt odit?</b>
        </article>
    <article>
        <h2> Segundo articulo</h2>
        <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Laudantium dolores ea expedita voluptas ad adipisci, quisquam repudiandae reprehenderit a at deserunt minus dolore error dicta architecto sequi. Officia, laboriosam quod. Magnam quod aperiam fugit atque debitis illo recusandae qui aut provident, rerum ex, aliquam neque modi pariatur expedita, voluptate eveniet autem molestias quo soluta voluptatum deleniti animi ipsa! Laborum, magnam! Provident dignissimos qui officiis quo rerum soluta ea tempora maiores tenetur veritatis! Cumque, dolore. Odio beatae, porro exercitationem qui voluptatum nisi in dicta rem doloremque amet, fugit nostrum eum aspernatur accusantium quaerat enim ex nemo sequi non temporibus et aperiam provident? Provident aperiam ullam deserunt quam eveniet id veritatis, dignissimos voluptate hic eos ducimus neque quod velit ad eius voluptatem esse atque, accusantium enim? Temporibus nesciunt modi repellat porro ratione repellendus reprehenderit laborum debitis ea voluptatum! Nemo, debitis deserunt. Corporis repellendus eos a aspernatur voluptates ratione laudantium impedit quia amet sint, sunt quo totam harum quas maiores veniam nisi quaerat odio fugit voluptas eaque voluptatum. Voluptates magnam facere consequatur ex officia itaque tenetur unde quos dolorum quisquam! Ipsam, voluptate. Iure magni molestiae dignissimos vel tempora nobis nisi natus commodi dicta hic quae corporis vero beatae, a, nesciunt distinctio sed consequatur.</b>
    </article>
    </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las rutas absolutas de tu archivo html y de tu imagen? (ejemplo: `C:/Users/FastedCoyote/imagen.jpg` o `/home/FastedCoyote/imagen.jpg`) Cuando suceden este tipo de errores, la mayoría de veces es por no usar correctamente las rutas relativas.

Comment: Pongo la ruta absoluta en el 'src'?

Comment: Sí, intenta con la ruta absoluta, esa no debería de fallar. Aunque preguntaba por las rutas absolutas de ambos archivos para corroborar que la ruta relativa de la imagen sea la correcta. Como sea, si aun con eso sigue sin funcionar, es probable que la hoja de estilos haya ocultado la imagen de alguna manera. Prueba a comentar/eliminar esa linea y si aparece la imagen entonces deberás de revisar cuál es el problema con el archivo CSS. También puede ser que tu imagen en realidad esté en otro formato que no sea compatible con tu navegador y por eso no se muestra.

Comment: he probado eso y nada... La carpeta de imágenes no me aparece en el inspeccionar de google quizá tenga que ver algo con eso

Comment: As probado también añadir los atributos ```height='valor'``` y ```width='valor'```, a tu etiqueta imagen?

Comment: Por que no pones esa imagen en un archivo CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la ruta de tu imagen sea correcta, cambia:

```
<img src="./imagenes/logosamisaw.png" alt="logo">
```

por esto:

```
<img src="../imagenes/logosamisaw.png" alt="logo">
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar :/

Comment: asegurate de estar usando la ruta correcta para tu imagen, y checa si está bien escrito el nombre de la misma. Coloca la ruta de tu archivo html y de tu imagen para ver si la estás colocando de forma correcta.

Comment: Supongo que estará bien escrito porque al hacer ctrl click me manda a la imagen y ya no me aparece le error, pero sigue sin aparecerme en la pagina web

Comment: limpia la caché del navegador entonces

Comment: Siempre regargo con ctrl f5 para que carguen los cambios que ya me ha pasado mas de una vez que hago cambios y no se ponen. Te pongo ahora una foto de VS Code para a ver si me puedes ayudar.

Comment: Probaste cambiar "imagenes" por "Imagenes"? las carpetas son case sensitive (a veces depende de sistema operativo) pero a como veo en el html que proporcionaste el nombre no cuadra. y si esta un nivel mas arriba seria ```html 
<img src="../Imagenes/logosamisaw.png" alt="logo">```